# Selenium Web driver Property file reading

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have one property file where given the path of IE driver stored

Written a class file to read the the path and in console printing.

I have another package where in @before method running the browser

```
System.getProperty("SelfConfig.Properties","pathname")
```

or

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","pathname")

driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 log.info("Implicit wait applied on the driver for 10 seconds");
```

My main intention i dont want to hard code the path in before method want to call from property files

I am new to this please help in to resolve

regards
abdul

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Reading properties file in Java example
    Properties props = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("c:/jdbc.properties");

    //loading properites from properties file
    props.load(fis);

    //reading proeprty
    String pathname = props.getProperty("jdbc.pathname");

    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",pathname)

    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Comment: I have created a file readproperties.java file and added this code Properties props = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("c:/jdbc.properties");

    //loading properites from properties file
    props.load(fis);

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",pathname)driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();property file given the path of the IE Driver pathname ="c://IE.exe but not working still in @beforetest props cannot be resolved

Answer (score 0):

I have created a file readproperties.java file and added this code Properties props = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("c:/systemconfig.properties");

```
//loading properites from properties file
props.load(fis);   ......................................................................i have another jave file calling @beforetest for browser and given this                                                             String pathname = props.getProperty("jdbc.pathname");

System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",pathname)

driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();    property file given the path of the IE Driver pathname ="c://IE.exe but not working still in @beforetest props cannot be resolved
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you using next property reader;

```
public class PropReader
{
    private static Properties propertyFile;
    private static String propertyFilename = "./src/main/resources/testdata.properties";
    public static String getStringPropValue(String key)
    {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;
        String result = "";
        try
        {
            prop.load(new FileInputStream(propertyFilename));
            result = prop.getProperty(key);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (input != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    input.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    //Reporter.log("Error while reading config: " + e.getMessage(), 2, true);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```